# Escaping quotes for HTML output?

Tags: php, html, escaping, double-quotes

So magic_quotes doesn't exist anymore in php, but I need a function like that (or maybe I don't?)
Let me quickly explain what I want to do:

```
<table>
    <button onclick="location.href='/test?colA=<?php echo $var1; ?>&colB=<?php echo $var1; ?>'">click</button>
</table>
```

The Problem: $var1 and $var2 can contain singlequotes and doublequotes.

Here is what I tried, which did not work:

```
$var1 = str_replace('"','&quot;',$var1);
$var1 = str_replace('\'','&#39;',$var1);

$var2 = str_replace('"','&quot;',$var2);
$var2 = str_replace('\'','&#39;',$var2);
```

Comment: This has little to do with magic_quotes. For this very context there are both [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: I'm actually already using htmlspecialchars. So I guess I have to use both? edit: no wait, i'm not sure if I do use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) on both vars would actually be sufficient. This escapes all special characters, including quotes.

Technically it's also in HTTP attribute context, so adding [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) would be professional.

Most correctly, though this is slightly overpedantic, you would first cover the URL parameter context, then the JavaScript string context, then HTML.

```
<table>
    <button onclick="location.href=<?= 
        htmlspecialchars(
            json_encode(
                "/test?" .
                http_build_query(
                    array("colA" => $var1, "colB" => $var2)
                )
            )
        )
    ?>">click</button>
</table>
```